# No connection between qml and python in pyside6

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyside, pyside6

I was writing a large program and encountered strange errors.
Wandering around Google, I came to a simple program that does not perform the expected functionality.

When you press a button, the number should increase and be displayed in the console and in the field. But for some reason the number is only displayed in the console. Moreover, if in qml you replace the function call with any line, then the line after clicking will be shown.

So this is interface in qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200
    title: "PySide QML Example"

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            text: "Increment"
            onClicked: {
                textField.text = backend.increment_counter().toString();
            }
        }

        TextField {
            id: textField
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            readOnly: true
        }
    }
}
```

And this is simple program

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, Slot, QObject
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


class Backend(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.counter = 0

    @Slot()
    def increment_counter(self):
        self.counter += 1
        print(self.counter)
        return self.counter


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    backend = Backend()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", backend)

    qml_file = "main.qml"
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_file))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I tried reinstalling pyside packages. And perhaps this will help: in a large program, the Component.onCompleted method did not work for me and methods from Python that were written inside qml were not called

Comment: You're directly calling the slot. You should instead provide a property that is updated whenever the slot is called, including a related "changed" signal emitted along with it and declared in the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @musicamante comment, it would be better for you provide a property with a change signal alongside your method:

- counter Property()
- counter_changed Signal()
- increment_counter() Slot()

I cleaned up your implementation of `increment_counter` to perform the increment but not return the value. The returning of the value will be done through the property.

As a property, we can clean up the QML code so that the `Button` onClicked only invokes the slot, but, the `TextField` is directly bound to the `counter` property.

```py
# main.py
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, Slot, QObject, Property, Signal
from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

class Backend(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._counter = 0
    counter_changed = Signal()
    def get_counter(self):
        return self._counter
    def set_counter(self, val):
        self._counter = val
        self.counter_changed.emit()
    @Slot()
    def increment_counter(self):
        self.set_counter(self.get_counter() + 1)
    counter = Property(int, get_counter, set_counter, notify=counter_changed)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    backend = Backend()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", backend)
    qml_file = "main.qml"
    engine.load(QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_file))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 400
    height: 200
    title: "PySide QML Example"

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            text: "Increment"
            onClicked: backend.increment_counter()
        }

        TextField {
            id: textField
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            readOnly: true
            text: backend.counter
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you rexample above it is only printing the increments because you missed the result in slot().

```
@Slot(result=int)
def increment_counter(self):
    self.counter += 1
    print(self.counter)
    return self.counter
```

I dont know if this solves the problem for your big program. But if i were you i would focus on one single question per post and also send the entire error messages that you recieve.

In this case for example there was a error message:

```
main.qml:16: TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
```