How to wire ApplicationWindow in pyside?
Brand new to Qt; using Pyside 6.
My pyside program gets a QQmlApplicationEngine and calls load to get my QML loaded. I can call engine.rootObjects() and there's one object, a QWindow.
First Question:
I want to start wiring up the application from python, but I can't seem to find things.
I can see there are child objects in that (root?) window by dumping them, but that's not actually helping me.
root = self.engine.rootObjects()[0]
for e in root.findChildren(QObject):
    e.dumpObjectInfo()             

Here are some things that return nothing:
b = self.root.findChildren(QPushButton)
b = self.root.findChildren(QObject,"button_1")

mb = root.findChildren(QObject,"mb1")
mb = root.findChildren(QMenuBar)
mb = root.findChild(QMenuBar,"menuBar")

The menuBar probably requires me to learn about otems with Actions, but just leave that be for this discussion. I simply can't find anything (e.g. random buttons that I placed in my layout.)
For that matter, how do I attach a new element (such as a button) to my layout ? If I programatically create another button, it wires up OK but it's just floating in a second window. I'll need to be able to find some appropriate parent, but I can't find anything at all!

Second question:
The QML has one button already wired:
onClicked: test_signal("button1 Test")

and python has this in my QApplication class:
@Slot(str)
def test_signal(self, msg : str):
    logging.info("test signal: %s from %s", msg, self)

But clicking the button doesn't run that method.
I must be greatly misunderstanding some basic things...
Here is the outline of my QML:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true

    signal test_signal(string msg)

    menuBar: MenuBar {
    id: mb1
    visible: true
    Menu {
    ...
    }
    }

    ColumnLayout {
    Button {
        id: button_1
        text: "Hello Test"
        onClicked: test_signal("button1 Test")
    }
    Button {
        id: button_2
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        text: "Push Me"
    }
    }
}


Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77539922/no-connection-between-qml-and-python-in-pyside6
